# Dropped columns reappear in columns.level

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex.

When I drop a column (e.g., containing a NaN) this column name still appears, when I call `df.columns.levels[1]`.

Minimal working example:

```
# Create DataFrame
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A','aa'),('A','bb'),('B','cc'),('B','dd')])
mydf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,4), columns=midx)
mydf.loc[1,('B','cc')] = np.nan

print(mydf)

>>        A                   B          
         aa        bb        cc        dd
0 -0.565250 -1.267290 -1.811422 -0.242648
1  0.138827  0.182022       NaN -0.286807
2  0.037163 -1.867622  1.259539 -0.485333
3  1.283082  1.030154  0.678748 -0.200731
4 -0.405116 -0.963670 -0.405438 -1.695403

# Drop column with NaN
mydf.dropna(how='any', axis=1, inplace=True)

print(mydf)
>>        A                   B
         aa        bb        dd
0 -0.565250 -1.267290 -0.242648
1  0.138827  0.182022 -0.286807
2  0.037163 -1.867622 -0.485333
3  1.283082  1.030154 -0.200731
4 -0.405116 -0.963670 -1.695403


mydf.columns.levels[1]
>> Index(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], dtype='object')
```

Alternatives I've tried, all ending with the same results:

```
new_df = mydf.dropna(how='any', axis=1)
new_df = mydf.dropna(how='any', axis=1).copy()
```

I need to access the list of present column names on level 1.
I have found a doable work-around, but I need to understand why this code above is not working as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html#pandas-multiindex-remove-unused-levels):

```
mydf.columns.levels[1]
#Index(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], dtype='object')

mydf.columns = mydf.columns.remove_unused_levels()

mydf.columns.levels[1]
#Index(['aa', 'bb', 'dd'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't be confused by the `MultiIndex` (a combination of single indexes) and each `Index` level. The `MultiIndex` represents a visible subset (at best the cartesian product) of the individual indexes that compose it.

```
# Index, level 0
>>> mydf.columns.levels[0]

# Index, level 1
>>> mydf.columns.levels[1]
Index(['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd'], dtype='object')

# Values, level 0
>>> mydf.columns.get_level_values(0)
Index(['A', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object')

# Values, level 1
>>> mydf.columns.get_level_values(1)
Index(['aa', 'bb', 'dd'], dtype='object')

# Cartesian product / dense multi-index
>>> pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mydf.columns.levels[0], mydf.columns.levels[1]])
MultiIndex([('A', 'aa'),
            ('A', 'bb'),
            ('A', 'cc'),
            ('A', 'dd'),
            ('B', 'aa'),
            ('B', 'bb'),
            ('B', 'cc'),
            ('B', 'dd')],
           )
```

So if you have an element that is no longer referenced, as @ScottBoston said, you can use `remove_unused_levels`.

> To reconstruct the MultiIndex with only the used levels, the remove_unused_levels() method may be used.

```
>>> mydf.columns.remove_unused_levels().levels
FrozenList([['A', 'B'], ['aa', 'bb', 'dd']])
#      level 0 --^     level 1 --^
```

More on [Defined levels in MultiIndex / advanced indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#defined-levels)